# Suppose there exist infinite subsets $X_1, . . , X_n$ of F such that f($x_1, . . , x_n$) = 0 for all ($x_1, .. , x_n$) ∈ $X_1 × · · · × X_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let f($t_1, . . . , t_n$) be a polynomial over a field F. Suppose there exist infinite subsets $X_1, . . . , X_n$ of F such that f($x_1, . . . , x_n$) = 0 for all ($x_1, . . . , x_n$) ∈ $X_1 × · · · × X_n$. Prove that f is the zero polynomial.

The related material is integral extensions, so I want to incorporate that area of maths to a solution.